# Android display refresh rate

Tags: android, refresh, rate

I'm developing an Android app which acts like a movie clapperboard/clapboard/slate. Is there any way in which I can set the display's refresh rate?

It is very important because when you edit the movie it's necessary to "land" on specific frames. The point is that if the timer is set to 25 frames per second, I need the display to update exactly 25 times per second, when the timer changes its value.

The problem on physical devices is that, let's say my Samsung Spica GT-I5700 returns a refresh rate of 62.016 which is totally inappropriate for a 25 fps timecode, and when editing you can see Frame1-Frame1-Frame2-Frame2 etc. or intermediaries, when you should see exactly Frame1-Frame2 etc.

The point is that I would need the refresh rate to be in sync with the timecode. If the user sets 25 fps, then the display should refresh exactly 25 times per second.
Any ideas, please? Thank you!

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to set an arbitrary refresh rate for any given device, whether it be android or not. Video circuitry is limited to the fidelity of its timers, and like all discrete systems, cannot operate with continuous precision.  However, this shouldn't be too much of a  problem.  If you're performing a dirty render (on demand), simply base your frame build around a 25Hz system timer, and the video hardware will render it during the next raster pass - a 60Hz raster pass will almost certainly occur within your 25Hz interval. You'll also have to consider frame-dropping when the system is too busy to honour a 25Hz interval.  If you're using fixed rate rendering, simply use the elapsed time between renders in order to determine the appropriate frame for a given frame rate.